# In Ubuntu 16.04, how can I resort files?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

In Ubuntu 16.04, how can I resort files in a folder? It seems I must choose name or last modified. I tried renaming to change when modified, but was left with original date.The files are a mix of .txt, .eml and .odt. I would like the files listed in another order.  When I made a change to the name, the time last modified remained the same. I don't know how to modify some non-text files. I am not tech-savvy and don't know the right words for much of this. I appreciate your patience. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to know what you mean. Resort for what? In detailed view you can sort by a lot of different criteria.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "resort files"? Do you simply mean "how do I sort files"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply renaming a file would not change its timestamp (modification date), you need to either make an actual change to the content of the file itself or use the `touch` command to change the modification date.

Run following command in Terminal

```
touch /path/to/file
```

to change the modification date of the file to current time. For example for a file named `sample-file` in your Documents folder, run

```
touch ~/Documents/sample-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can sort files in Nautilus (the File Manager) you get more options when using the `ls` (**l**i**s**t files and directories (not **L**ost **S**aloon)) command and changing the parameters passed to it.

A brief summary from the LostSaloon: [how to sort the output of ‘ls command’ in linux command line](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-sort-the-output-of-ls-in-linux/)

- `ls -1` (yes that is a one not an L). Sort by name
- `ls -1r` sort by name in reverse order
- `ls -lr --group-directories-first` Sort by name in reverse order with directories listed first (they usually appear in blue text)
- `ls -t` sort by date last modified
- `ls -S` sort by file size (largest to smallest)
- `ls -S` sort by file size (smallest to largest)
- `ls -X` sort by extension

For even more power pipe `ls` output (send output) to the `sort` command. For example to sort files on owner user ID:

```
ls -l | sort -k 3
```

Whilst answering this question I found something interesting:

```
$ ls -laSr
total 2216
-rw-r--r--  1 rick rick           0 Aug  3  2018 .sudo_as_admin_successful
-rw-r-----  1 rick rick           0 Apr 16 17:14 .gksu.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick           0 Aug 23  2018 File A
(... SNIP ...)
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick      143383 Sep 30  2018 dbus-monitor-plugin.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick      147247 Sep 30  2018 dbus-monitor-lid-close.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick      177948 Oct 16  2018 java_error_in_STUDIO_9901.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      350821 Dec 17 18:04 trace89.dat.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick 20000000000 Apr  7 19:50 foo
```

I must have used the `sudo` command that created the file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      350821 Dec 17 18:04 trace89.dat.gz
```

One must be careful with `sudo` because it can change the owner of files in a regular user's directory. This happened here but this particular file is of little concern.

I must have forgot an experiment that created an extraordinary large file. I should have deleted this file:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 rick rick 20000000000 Apr  7 19:50 foo
```